# Can CA certificate be imported in Trusted people store?

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, adfs, ca

I am working on ADFS external authentication project. I am using a self signed certificate, which is imported in Trusted people store. I need to verify whether importing a CA certificate to Trusted people store work or not.

When I tried using the CA certificate in Trusted people, it does not work. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-signed certificate or you can purchase from third party vendor it will work if you import into any ADFS store or trusted store. But the certificates must met the ADFS certificate requirements. Kindly check the requirements in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/design/ad-fs-requirements#BKMK_1)

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_7U2TUTC7Egj9cqh&Q_CHL=gl
>